# Microsoft GraphAPI 403 error getting users' events in SPfx app

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

I wrote a SharePoint SPfx Application  hosted on SharePoint Online using the Microsoft GraphAPI to grab user profile information as well as calendar events. Per microsoft documents I declared my scopes inside the package-solution.json file and approved the request via the SharePoint APi management page. I am able to read everybody profile information, however, I get an error 403 when I try to access calendar events but my own. The users' calendar are not private, they open to the entire organization.

*Package-solution.json Permission request*

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "User.Read"
      },
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "User.ReadBasic.All"
      },
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "People.Read"
      },
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Calendars.Read"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Admin Approved request image

[Screen of approved app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7im7.png)

request code:

```
private _searchUserCalendar(keyword: string): Promise<any[]> {
    console.log("connection to GraphAPI event domain")
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      this._context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient()
        .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
          client
            .api(`/users/${keyword}/calendar/events`) // The api i.e> /me | /users
            .version('v1.0')
            .select("showAs,start,subject, end")
            .top(5)
            .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log("ooops somethign went wrong get events",error);
                reject(error);
              }
              var users:Array<any>=new Array<any>();

              // Map the JSON response to the output array
              if (response != null && response != undefined) {
                console.log(response);
                response.value.map((item: any) => {
                  console.log("found events for:", item)
                }); // mapping over users
              }
              resolve(users);  

            });
        });
    });
  }
```

Error response

```
{error: {code: "ErrorAccessDenied", message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",…}}
error: {code: "ErrorAccessDenied", message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",…}
code: "ErrorAccessDenied"
message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
innerError: {request-id: "5dca3d4f-ab4c-4237-8ff4-78d8cacbd43b", date: "2020-01-16T19:05:26"}
request-id: "5dca3d4f-ab4c-4237-8ff4-78d8cacbd43b"
date: "2020-01-16T19:05:26"
```

I've tried everything, any help would be greatly appreciated.

- I tested my request on graph explorer and that worked fine
- I uninstalled/re-installed the app
- I rejected and re-approved the permissions request on the API management dashboard
- I changed the request URL from using user id to using emails (only worked for my profile but still didn't work for anybody else)
- I had users share their calendar with me and give read/write permissions, still didn't work because the permission is application specific and not user delegated.

Comment: Can you add descriptions of things you have done?

Comment: @Fred I edited my post with a list of what I tried, let me know if you need any other clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.Read`, and `User.ReadBasic.All` don't have the permissions to do what you are trying to do.

This [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars) talks about calendar reading shared events.

> As an example, Garth has shared with John his default calendar and given John read access. If John has signed into your app and provided delegated permissions (Calendars.Read.Shared or Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared), your app will be able to access Garth's default calendar and events in that calendar as described below.

Can you try adding `Calendar.Read.Shared`

Comment: hmmm... I'm actually able to read everybody's profile information just fine. Maybe I should have said it in the description. I'm only having issue with accessing the events. `Calendars.Read.Shared` per the documents will show shared events and `Calendars.read` will show only the user's event. However, at this point I'm desperate so I will try it. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: You have ```User.ReadBasic.All``` which gives you basic profile information (display name, first and last name, email address, open extensions and photo.) You need more permisssions (like ```User.Read.All```  or  ```Calender.Read.Shared```) to access more information

Comment: you might be right, I'm in the process of pushing the new update to the permission, I'll keep posted if it works

Answer (score 0):

After trying different permission scopes including the ones suggested by @chad, it seems that **Calendar.Read.Shared** worked. However, it worked because it is a delegated permission forwhich the users must implicitly share their calendar with the entire organization or the signed-in user. This is misleading and contrary to what I read in the graphAPI documentations found 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions) under Calendar > Application permission:

> Calendars.Read |  Read calendars in all mailboxes Allows the app to read
>   events of all calendars without a signed-in user.

... and

> Calendars.Read.Shared |   Read user and shared calendars  Allows the app
>   to read events in all calendars that the user can access, including
>   delegate and shared calendars.

Therefore, according to the previous statements, All i need is Calendars.Read in order to read all events in a user's calendar created by said user. The logic of using *Calendars.Read.Shared* would be to also read all events shared by the user, including those not created but shared with the user.

Finally, I marked this as answered because it is the only thing that worked for me (somewhat) and not because it solved the original issue. The documentation on this topic is contradictory and confusing. For now this is my answer unless Microsoft changed something or clarify the issue or you found something else or/and my logic is flawed. If my logic and understanding is flawed please post a response and let me know. Afterall, this is what the community is for.

Thank you